# How add class to last TD in table in which is rowspan. With jQuery

Tags: jquery

Hello I have this table

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>n</td>
    <td rowspan=2>n</td>
    <td>n</td>
    <td>n</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan=2>y</td>
    <td>n</td>
    <td rowspan=2>y</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>y</td>
    <td>y</td>
</tr>
```

and I need mark last visual TD by class `.last`. Without rowspan there isnt problem, I can use

```
$('table tr:last td').addClass('last');
```

**I need add class `.last` to `td` with value y**

Some examples with cells with 'y' which I want to mark witch class
http://jsfiddle.net/9gtMa/

http://jsfiddle.net/MQh8u/

http://jsfiddle.net/zL6Pe/

I need output like

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>n</td>
        <td rowspan=2>n</td>
        <td>n</td>
        <td>n</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan=2 class='last'>y</td>
        <td>n</td>
        <td rowspan=2 class='last'>y</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='last'>y</td>
        <td class='last'>y</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you should add last to td not tr, $('table td:last').addClass('last');

Comment: 4,8,9. Here 4 have rowspan but not a last td of TR. 8, 9 not have rowspan. Please say clear

Comment: I think the need is for a multiple selector... the `td` with a rowspan on row 2, and both `td`s on row 3

Comment: Can you post what the markup should look like after the last class is assigned?

Comment: I add output. My goal is, add class to last TD in each column

Answer (score 1):

Use a multiple selector to get the last `<td>` with a rowspan using `table td[rowspan]:last` and then both `<td>`s in the last row using `table tr:last td`

```
$('table td[rowspan]:last, table tr:last td').addClass('last');
```

Per your example in http://jsfiddle.net/qEhng/, you can find the max row index with a td[rowspan] and then set the class on it like this. Not terribly efficient, but it will only assign the `.last` class to the `<td>`s with a rowspan that are on the highest row index. If you *only* want to assign `.last` to the second to last row, you can add additional logic to check the row index, however it will get tricky if you have a rowspan that is greater than 2...

```
$('table tr:last td').addClass('last');
var maxRow = 0;
$('table td[rowspan]').each(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    if (row>maxRow) maxRow=row;
});
$('table td[rowspan]').each(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    if (row==maxRow) $(this).addClass('last');
});
```

Here is the code to only add the `.last` class to the td with the max rowspan that flows to the last row - http://jsfiddle.net/qEhng/5/

```
$('table tr:last td').addClass('last');
var maxRow = 0;
var rowSpan = 0;
$('table td[rowspan]').each(function(){
    var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
    if (row>maxRow){
        maxRow=row;
        rowSpan=0;
    }
    if ($(this).attr('rowspan')>rowSpan) rowSpan = $(this).attr('rowspan');
});
if (maxRow==$('table tr:last td').parent().parent().children().index($('table tr:last td').parent())-(rowSpan-1)){
    $('table td[rowspan]').each(function(){
        var row = $(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent());
        if (row==maxRow && $(this).attr('rowspan')==rowSpan) $(this).addClass('last');
    });
}
```

If you want all rows that touch the final row (via rowspan or not), then the following code will work (see http://jsfiddle.net/zL6Pe/ )

```
$('table tr:last td').addClass('last');
var rows = $('table tr:last').parent().children().length;
$('table td[rowspan]').each(function(){
   if ($(this).parent().parent().children().index($(this).parent())+parseInt($(this).attr('rowspan'))==rows) $(this).addClass('last');
});​
```

Comment: Hello, i add more examples. Your last added code isn't properly working on last one. See http://jsfiddle.net/zL6Pe/1/

Comment: Edited the last example - you need to reset the `rowSpan` counter when the `maxRow` value is updated.

Comment: If this works for you, I would appreciate you marking it as the answer, thanks!

Comment: I tried it on last example (http://jsfiddle.net/zL6Pe/) and it doesn't work. I have one solution of this problem in progress. I will finish it tomorrow.

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't working... you want all cells that touch the bottom to get the `.last` class?

Comment: Yes. In that example, every cell with value 'y' should be green

Answer (score 0):

I find this sollution. Isn't working on jsfiddle example, I don't know why but it seems to be working at all.

```
getOffSet = function(rowSpansPerCol, startIndex){
    var offSet = 0;
    for(i=startIndex;i<rowSpansPerCol.length;i++){
        if(rowSpansPerCol[i]==1){
            return offSet;
        }
        else{
            offSet+1;
        }
    }
    return offSet;
}

markCells = function(table){
    var rows = table.find('tr');
    var columnCount = table.find('tr:first td').size();
    var rowSpansPerCol = new Array();

    rows.each(function(rowIndex) {
        jQuery(this).find('td').each(
                        function(colIndex) {
                            var offset = getOffSet(rowSpansPerCol, colIndex);
                            if ((rowSpansPerCol[colIndex+offset] == null || rowSpansPerCol[colIndex+offset]==1) && (jQuery(this).attr('rowSpan')+rowIndex == rows.size() || rows.size() == rowIndex+1)) {
                                jQuery(this).addClass('last')
                            } else {
                                rowSpansPerCol[colIndex+offset] = jQuery(this).attr('rowSpan');
                            }

                        })
})  
}

markCells(jQuery('table'));
```